# HTML input type as email & password

Tags: python, html

I am writing a basic html program to give input as email and password. Below is the html program

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action='show_commands_html.py' method='get'>
      <label for="myname">Enter Your Name</label>
      <input id="myname" type="email" name="firstname" value="test@in.com" />
  <label for="mypass">Enter Your password</label>
      <input id="mypass" type="password" name="Password" value="test121$" />
      <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

respective python code

```
import os
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
qs = os.environ['QUERY_STRING']
if 'firstname' in qs:
name = qs.split('&')[0]
name = name.split('=')[1]
if 'Password' in qs:
passw = qs.split('=')[2]
username = name
password = passw
print "<html>" 
print "<body>"
print "<h1>%s</h1>" %username
print "</pre>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
print "<html>"
print "<body>"
print "<h1>%s</h1>" %password
print "</pre>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

I am getting below answers from web page

```
test%40in.com
test121%24
```

Instead of

```
test@in.com
test121$
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Please use at least the `cgi` module from the standard library instead of reinventing the wheel here. Even better `bottle` or `flask` if third party modules are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add UTF-8 inside `<head>`.

**Method 1.**
You can add new line inside your .py code,

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

**Method 2.** Add new string and test if it works.

```
u = 'idzie wąż wąską dróżką'
uu = u.decode('utf8')
s = uu.encode('cp1250')
print(s)
```

**Method 3.** Add these 2 lines above your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

**Tip**

Make sure, you changed in your code editor:

Settings -> File Encoding -> *Switch to:* Unicode (UTF-8)

Comment: You mean like this "Content-type: text/html charset=utf-8" ?

Comment: I tried like this 
    print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n"
 but same result

Comment: ? any help please

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as both values are ASCII only, just URL encoded.